# c++ thread does not execute

Tags: c++, multithreading

The `thread1` function does not seem to get executed

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <thread>
   #include <condition_variable>
   #include <queue>

   std::condition_variable cv;
   std::mutex mu;
   std::queue<int> queue;
   bool ready;

    static void thread1() {
        while(!ready) {std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));}

        while(ready && queue.size() <= 4) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
                cv.wait(lk, [&]{return !queue.empty();});

                queue.push(2);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        ready = false;
        std::thread t(thread1);

        while(queue.size() <= 4) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mu);
                queue.push(1);
            }

            ready = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }

        t.join();

        for(int i = 0; i <= queue.size(); i++) {
                int a = queue.front();
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
                queue.pop();
        }

        return 0;
}
```

On my Mac the output is `1 2 1 2` but in my ubuntu its `1 1 1`. I'm compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o thread.out thread.cpp && ./thread.out`. Am I missing something?

Comment: There's no guarantee that thread1 will be able to grab the mutex before your main loop locks it again. That's just how multi-threading goes, it can be unpredictable.

Comment: But I thought the conditional variable in thread1 would lock the mutex with wait and sync both main and thread1. What can I can do to sync to run in sequence?

Comment: You have a race condition. `thread1` could execute `queue.size()` while `main` executes `queue.push(1)`, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Okay I added a ready check with a sleep to thread1 to prevent undefined, updated code in question. But race condition still exists.

Comment: You're accessing `ready` from two separate threads, but `ready` is not considered `atomic`. Accessing a non-`atomic` value from multiple threads is unsafe/unwise/(maybe UB?)

Comment: @Tas But only one thread is writing, and on any machine that this is likely being run on, boolean writes and reads are atomic. Probably not wise but I don't think this is UB; maybe unspecified.

Comment: @NirFriedman It's a data race and 100% undefined behavior. Atomicity of access is likely not going to be an issue here, but memory ordering could very well be (which is the second guarantee that `std::atomic` gives you besides atomicity). Since the flag is part of the condition guarded by the `condition_variable`, it should be protected by its mutex, same as the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by making the second thread wait on a separate predicate on a separate conditional variable. I'm not sure if queue.size() is thread safe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::condition_variable cv2;
std::mutex mu;
std::queue<int> queue;
bool tick;
bool tock;

static void thread1() {
while(queue.size() < 6) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    cv2.wait(lk, []{return tock;});

    queue.push(1);

    tock = false;
    tick = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
}

int main() {
tick = false;
tock = true;
std::thread t(thread1);

while(queue.size() < 6) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return tick;});

    queue.push(2);

    tick = false;
    tock = true;
    cv2.notify_one();
}

t.join();

while(!queue.empty()) {
    int r = queue.front();
    queue.pop();

    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= queue.size(); i++) {
    int a = queue.front();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    queue.pop();
}
```

Is undefined behavior. A for loop that goes from 0 to `size` runs `size+1` times. I would suggest that you write this in the more idiomatic style for a queue:

```
while(!queue.empty()) {
    int a = queue.front();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    queue.pop();
}
```

When I run this on coliru, which I assume runs some kind of *nix machine, I get 4 1's: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8de5b01e87e8549e.

Again, you haven't specified anything that would force each thread to run a certain amount of times. You only (try to*) cause an invariant where the queue will reach size 4, either way. It just happens to be that on the machines that we ran it on, thread 2 never manages to acquire the mutex.

This example will be more interesting if you add more work or even (just for pedagogical purposes) delays at various points. Simulating that the two threads are actually doing work. If you add sleeps at various points you can ensure that the two threads alternate, though depending where you add them you may see your invariant of 4 elements in the thread break!

*Note that even your 4 element invariant on the queue, is not really an invariant. It is possible (though very unlikely) that *both* threads pass the while condition at the exact same moment, when there are 3 elements in the queue. One acquires the lock first and pushes, and then the other. So you can end up with 5 elements in the queue! (as you can see, asynchronous programming is tricky). In particular you really need to check the queue size when you have the lock in order for this to work.